# Find the area of the convex quadrilateral when you have the value of one diagonal and it's intersection point

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a convex quadrilateral and E is the intersection point of their diagonals if $DE=3$ and $BE=12$ find $\frac{ADC}{ABCD}$ I know the length of one diagonal so that's $BD=15$ and their now two triangles and I'm stuck.

Comment: You won't be able to find the area - you don't have enough information - but you can still find the ratio that is asked for. Draw a few quadrilaterals and look for the area of $ADC$ as a fraction of the area of the whole thing. Consider all four small triangles created by the diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

Draw perpendiculars from B and D to diagonal AC. Let the lengths of these perpendiculars be h1 and h2, Let E be the acute angle between the 2 digonals.

Then h1=3*sin(E) and h2=12=12*Sin(E)
Area of ACD = AC * h1/2
Area of ACB = AC * h2/2
Area of ABCD = AC * (h1+h2)/2

so ACD/ABCD = h1/(h1+h2) = 3*Sin(E)/15*Sin(E) = 3/15=1/5